# How can I get source maps with the webpack less loader?

Tags: less, webpack

Is it possible to get source maps when using the less loader with webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the source code, [no](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader/blob/master/index.js).

Technically I suppose it's possible if you pass a sourcemap JSON obtained from LESS compiler as the last parameter to the [result callback](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader/blob/master/index.js#L84). To obtain it, I suppose you'd need to [supply `writeSourceMap` like in this sample](https://github.com/digisfera/less-files/blob/master/index.js#L50) to [`less-loader` `render` call](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader/blob/master/index.js#L77).

Comment: press y before copying lines from github, so the link refers to the current version of the file. Those links to github are now pointing to something else

Comment: Thanks, I know about this now. I wish you told me this two years ago :-)